# What does 4*1 Panel-up mean?

Tags: pcb, layout

I believe the number 4 corresponds to the number of individual PCBs and the number 1 is for one panel.

1. Is this the way panelized PCBs are commonly referenced?  With an asterisk mark?
2. What does the "-up" mean in Panel-up?
3. **Is there a more common way when to refer to quantities and descriptions of panelized PCBs?**

Here is a [link](http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/shiyu1112/product-detailIKpJgHAPJLcj/China-PCB-with-4-1-Panel-up-V-Cut.html) to where I saw the term used.

Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: 4*1 probably means the panel is laid out as 4 PCB's wide by 1 high. Think it would probably be better written as ```4 x 1```. I think Panel-up is just a bad Chinese to English translation - as is Panelled up.

Comment: "4*1" stand for "four by one". I.e. 4 columns, 1 row.

Answer (score 3):

"4*1" is already covered in the comments: an two-dimensional array of 4 boards by 1 board.

"panel-up" is likely a neologism derived from ["n-up"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-up), which is a method of arranging multiple smaller images of pages on a single printed page which panelization imitates.